# Is it a bad practice in PHP to use an array without initiation with an empty array?

Tags: php

Is it fine to write code like this in PHP:

```
function calculateSome() {
    $numbers['big'] = [];
    ...
}
```

instead of this:

```
function calculateSome() {
    $numbers = [];
    $numbers['big'] = [];
    ...
}
```

?

Comment: IF this is the first usage of `$numbers`, you're fine. The array is created automatically for you. However, if `$numbers` already is set, your second line may not produce the value you expect. I'd say just create the array manually each time so you always know what `$numbers` contains, especially if you intend to ever copy/paste your code.

Comment: What @liftoff says. Also just better from a readability standpoint.

Comment: @ficuscr Yes, thanks. That answers my question.